# Android camera preview displays green screen

Tags: android, android-camera, android-5.0-lollipop

I have implemented camera preview on Android >= 4.1.2. On Android 5 on Galaxy S4 (two different devices) view displays three camera previews and green screen:

[image]

On Galaxy S3 (Android 4.3), Galaxy S2 (Android 4.1.2) and Galaxy Tab S (Android 5.0.1) it works correctly.

This is my code below:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.hardware.Camera;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;

import java.util.List;

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public class CameraView extends SurfaceView {

    private boolean inPreview = false;
    private boolean surfaceCreated = false;

    private Camera camera = null;

    private Camera.Size previewSize = null;

    public CameraView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder = getHolder();
        SurfaceHolder.Callback surfaceHolderCallback = new SurfaceHolder.Callback() {

            @Override
            public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
                surfaceCreated = true;
                try {
                    camera = Camera.open();
                    camera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    camera.release();
                    camera = null;
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {
                if (holder.getSurface() == null || camera == null) {
                    return;
                }
                camera.stopPreview();
                List<Camera.Size> sizes = camera.getParameters().getSupportedPictureSizes();
                previewSize = getOptimalPreviewSize(sizes, width, height);
                startPreview();
            }

            @Override
            public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
                surfaceCreated = false;
                if (camera != null) {
                    camera.stopPreview();
                    camera.release();
                    camera = null;
                }
            }
        };
        surfaceHolder.addCallback(surfaceHolderCallback);
        surfaceHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
    }

    public void onResume() {
        if(!inPreview && camera != null && surfaceCreated) {
            startPreview();
        }
    }

    public void onPause() {
        if(camera != null) {
            camera.stopPreview();
            inPreview = false;
        }
    }

    private void startPreview() {
        Camera.Parameters parameters = camera.getParameters();
        parameters.setPreviewSize(previewSize.width, previewSize.height);
        camera.setParameters(parameters);
        camera.startPreview();
        inPreview = true;
    }

    private Camera.Size getOptimalPreviewSize(List<Camera.Size> sizes, int w, int h) {
        final double ASPECT_TOLERANCE = 0.05;
        double targetRatio = (double) w / h;
        if (sizes == null)
            return null;

        Camera.Size optimalSize = null;
        double minDiff = Double.MAX_VALUE;

        for (Camera.Size size : sizes) {
            double ratio = (double) size.width / size.height;
            if (Math.abs(ratio - targetRatio) > ASPECT_TOLERANCE)
                continue;
            if (Math.abs(size.height - h) < minDiff) {
                optimalSize = size;
                minDiff = Math.abs(size.height - h);
            }
        }

        if (optimalSize == null) {
            minDiff = Double.MAX_VALUE;
            for (Camera.Size size : sizes) {
                if (Math.abs(size.height - h) < minDiff) {
                    optimalSize = size;
                    minDiff = Math.abs(size.height - h);
                }
            }
        }
        return optimalSize;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private CameraView cameraView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        cameraView = new CameraView(this);
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
        cameraView.setLayoutParams(params);
        setContentView(cameraView);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        cameraView.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        cameraView.onPause();
    }
}
```

I support only landscape mode.

Comment: What value is being used for `optimalSize` on the devices where it's failing?

Comment: Did you look to see if there's anything interesting in the logs?

Comment: Very typical. The 4.3 stock ROM does not report this preview size: [preview-size-values=1920x1080,1440x1080,1280x960,1280x720,1056x864,1024x768,1008x566,800x600,800x480,800x450,720x480,640x480,528x432,480x320,480x270,352x288,320x240,176x144](http://www.androidfragmentation.com/database/v/dr/656498/oem/samsung/dm/GT-I9500/carrier/GOLAN%20T), but the Lollipop update was not validated fully (*by the way, how long dod you wait for it?*)

Comment: Wait for what? Lollipop update?

Comment: Is this issue if fixed, I am also facing same issue.

Comment: Have you fixed this issue ?

Comment: Is this issue is fixed, I am also facing the same issue?